# Vue Component Props are not being updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my data I have an object `program`. I load a list of objects asynchronously and add it to `program.sections`.

```
    async loadSections() {
        if (this.user == null && this.program.sections) { return }
        await this.$store.dispatch('loadProgramSections', {program: this.program, user: this.user});
        console.log('loaded Sections', this.program);

        // this.$set(this.program, 'sections', this.progrmm.sections)
        // this.$nextTick(() => { this.$forceUpdate(); }) 
    },
```

My UI looks like this:

```
<Section :program="program" ></Section>
```

So I pass my `program` object down to my Sections component

In my console log I can see that the field `programm.sections` is indeed my array of objects but my UI does not get changed. When I put my UI code from the Sections component directly in to my page, it gets updated and the data is dispalyed correctly but when I use the component the props are not being updated correctly.

I already tried the commented lines in my code but it doesn't work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This probably would have fixed it `this.$set(this.program, 'sections', this.progrmm.sections)` but you spelled `this.progrmm` incorrectly. I'd just instantiate it in your data: `program: { sections : {} }`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for the help but neither seem to work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a new object reference in `this.program`:

```
async loadSections() {
    if (this.user == null && this.program.sections) { return }
    await this.$store.dispatch('loadProgramSections', {program: this.program, user: this.user});
    console.log('loaded Sections', this.program);

    // assign a new object reference
    this.program = Object.asssign({}, this.program);
},
```

Also make sure you initialize `program` in data() section.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that Vue cannot detect the changes in some situations.

e.g. set a item to an array or set an additional property to an object

That's the crux of the problem. You might need [Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).